# Loading jQuery script and getting TypeError: $.fn.appear.run is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've loaded a animation script for CSS into my markup, however I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: $.fn.appear.run is not a function

Anyone have any ideas why and how I can sort that?

```
/*
 * CSS3 Animate it
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Jack McCourt
 * https://github.com/kriegar/css3-animate-it
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * 
 * I utilise the jQuery.appear plugin within this javascript file so here is a link to that too
 * https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear
 *
 * I also utilise the jQuery.doTimeout plugin for the data-sequence functionality so here is a link back to them.
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/
 */
(function($) {
  var selectors = [];

  var check_binded = false;
  var check_lock = false;
  var defaults = {
    interval: 250,
    force_process: false
  }
  var $window = $(window);

  var $prior_appeared;

  function process() {
    check_lock = false;
    for (var index = 0; index < selectors.length; index++) {
      var $appeared = $(selectors[index]).filter(function() {
        return $(this).is(':appeared');
      });

      $appeared.trigger('appear', [$appeared]);

      if ($prior_appeared) {

        var $disappeared = $prior_appeared.not($appeared);
        $disappeared.trigger('disappear', [$disappeared]);
      }
      $prior_appeared = $appeared;
    }
  }

  // "appeared" custom filter
  $.expr[':']['appeared'] = function(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    if (!$element.is(':visible')) {
      return false;
    }

    var window_left = $window.scrollLeft();
    var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
    var offset = $element.offset();
    var left = offset.left;
    var top = offset.top;

    if (top + $element.height() >= window_top &&
        top - ($element.data('appear-top-offset') || 0) <= window_top + $window.height() &&
        left + $element.width() >= window_left &&
        left - ($element.data('appear-left-offset') || 0) <= window_left + $window.width()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    // watching for element's appearance in browser viewport
    appear: function(options) {
      var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
      var selector = this.selector || this;
      if (!check_binded) {
        var on_check = function() {
          if (check_lock) {
            return;
          }
          check_lock = true;

          setTimeout(process, opts.interval);
        };

        $(window).scroll(on_check).resize(on_check);
        check_binded = true;
      }

      if (opts.force_process) {
        setTimeout(process, opts.interval);
      }
      selectors.push(selector);
      return $(selector);
    }
  });

  $.extend({
    // force elements's appearance check
    force_appear: function() {
      if (check_binded) {
        process();
        return true;
      };
      return false;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);



/*!
 * jQuery doTimeout: Like setTimeout, but better! - v1.0 - 3/3/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */

// Script: jQuery doTimeout: Like setTimeout, but better!
//
// *Version: 1.0, Last updated: 3/3/2010*
// 
// Project Home - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/
// GitHub       - http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/
// Source       - http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/raw/master/jquery.ba-dotimeout.js
// (Minified)   - http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-dotimeout/raw/master/jquery.ba-dotimeout.min.js (1.0kb)
// 
// About: License
// 
// Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman,
// Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
// http://benalman.com/about/license/
// 
// About: Examples
// 
// These working examples, complete with fully commented code, illustrate a few
// ways in which this plugin can be used.
// 
// Debouncing      - http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/
// Delays, Polling - http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/delay-poll/
// Hover Intent    - http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/
// 
// About: Support and Testing
// 
// Information about what version or versions of jQuery this plugin has been
// tested with, what browsers it has been tested in, and where the unit tests
// reside (so you can test it yourself).
// 
// jQuery Versions - 1.3.2, 1.4.2
// Browsers Tested - Internet Explorer 6-8, Firefox 2-3.6, Safari 3-4, Chrome 4-5, Opera 9.6-10.1.
// Unit Tests      - http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/unit/
// 
// About: Release History
// 
// 1.0 - (3/3/2010) Callback can now be a string, in which case it will call
//       the appropriate $.method or $.fn.method, depending on where .doTimeout
//       was called. Callback must now return `true` (not just a truthy value)
//       to poll.
// 0.4 - (7/15/2009) Made the "id" argument optional, some other minor tweaks
// 0.3 - (6/25/2009) Initial release

(function($){
  '$:nomunge'; // Used by YUI compressor.

  var cache = {},

    // Reused internal string.
    doTimeout = 'doTimeout',

    // A convenient shortcut.
    aps = Array.prototype.slice;

  // Method: jQuery.doTimeout
  // 
  // Initialize, cancel, or force execution of a callback after a delay.
  // 
  // If delay and callback are specified, a doTimeout is initialized. The
  // callback will execute, asynchronously, after the delay. If an id is
  // specified, this doTimeout will override and cancel any existing doTimeout
  // with the same id. Any additional arguments will be passed into callback
  // when it is executed.
  // 
  // If the callback returns true, the doTimeout loop will execute again, after
  // the delay, creating a polling loop until the callback returns a non-true
  // value.
  // 
  // Note that if an id is not passed as the first argument, this doTimeout will
  // NOT be able to be manually canceled or forced. (for debouncing, be sure to
  // specify an id).
  // 
  // If id is specified, but delay and callback are not, the doTimeout will be
  // canceled without executing the callback. If force_mode is specified, the
  // callback will be executed, synchronously, but will only be allowed to
  // continue a polling loop if force_mode is true (provided the callback
  // returns true, of course). If force_mode is false, no polling loop will
  // continue, even if the callback returns true.
  // 
  // Usage:
  // 
  // > jQuery.doTimeout( [ id, ] delay, callback [, arg ... ] );
  // > jQuery.doTimeout( id [, force_mode ] );
  // 
  // Arguments:
  // 
  //  id - (String) An optional unique identifier for this doTimeout. If id is
  //    not specified, the doTimeout will NOT be able to be manually canceled or
  //    forced.
  //  delay - (Number) A zero-or-greater delay in milliseconds after which
  //    callback will be executed. 
  //  callback - (Function) A function to be executed after delay milliseconds.
  //  callback - (String) A jQuery method to be executed after delay
  //    milliseconds. This method will only poll if it explicitly returns
  //    true.
  //  force_mode - (Boolean) If true, execute that id's doTimeout callback
  //    immediately and synchronously, continuing any callback return-true
  //    polling loop. If false, execute the callback immediately and
  //    synchronously but do NOT continue a callback return-true polling loop.
  //    If omitted, cancel that id's doTimeout.
  // 
  // Returns:
  // 
  //  If force_mode is true, false or undefined and there is a
  //  yet-to-be-executed callback to cancel, true is returned, but if no
  //  callback remains to be executed, undefined is returned.

  $[doTimeout] = function() {
    return p_doTimeout.apply( window, [ 0 ].concat( aps.call( arguments ) ) );
  };

  // Method: jQuery.fn.doTimeout
  // 
  // Initialize, cancel, or force execution of a callback after a delay.
  // Operates like <jQuery.doTimeout>, but the passed callback executes in the
  // context of the jQuery collection of elements, and the id is stored as data
  // on the first element in that collection.
  // 
  // If delay and callback are specified, a doTimeout is initialized. The
  // callback will execute, asynchronously, after the delay. If an id is
  // specified, this doTimeout will override and cancel any existing doTimeout
  // with the same id. Any additional arguments will be passed into callback
  // when it is executed.
  // 
  // If the callback returns true, the doTimeout loop will execute again, after
  // the delay, creating a polling loop until the callback returns a non-true
  // value.
  // 
  // Note that if an id is not passed as the first argument, this doTimeout will
  // NOT be able to be manually canceled or forced (for debouncing, be sure to
  // specify an id).
  // 
  // If id is specified, but delay and callback are not, the doTimeout will be
  // canceled without executing the callback. If force_mode is specified, the
  // callback will be executed, synchronously, but will only be allowed to
  // continue a polling loop if force_mode is true (provided the callback
  // returns true, of course). If force_mode is false, no polling loop will
  // continue, even if the callback returns true.
  // 
  // Usage:
  // 
  // > jQuery('selector').doTimeout( [ id, ] delay, callback [, arg ... ] );
  // > jQuery('selector').doTimeout( id [, force_mode ] );
  // 
  // Arguments:
  // 
  //  id - (String) An optional unique identifier for this doTimeout, stored as
  //    jQuery data on the element. If id is not specified, the doTimeout will
  //    NOT be able to be manually canceled or forced.
  //  delay - (Number) A zero-or-greater delay in milliseconds after which
  //    callback will be executed. 
  //  callback - (Function) A function to be executed after delay milliseconds.
  //  callback - (String) A jQuery.fn method to be executed after delay
  //    milliseconds. This method will only poll if it explicitly returns
  //    true (most jQuery.fn methods return a jQuery object, and not `true`,
  //    which allows them to be chained and prevents polling).
  //  force_mode - (Boolean) If true, execute that id's doTimeout callback
  //    immediately and synchronously, continuing any callback return-true
  //    polling loop. If false, execute the callback immediately and
  //    synchronously but do NOT continue a callback return-true polling loop.
  //    If omitted, cancel that id's doTimeout.
  // 
  // Returns:
  // 
  //  When creating a <jQuery.fn.doTimeout>, the initial jQuery collection of
  //  elements is returned. Otherwise, if force_mode is true, false or undefined
  //  and there is a yet-to-be-executed callback to cancel, true is returned,
  //  but if no callback remains to be executed, undefined is returned.

  $.fn[doTimeout] = function() {
    var args = aps.call( arguments ),
      result = p_doTimeout.apply( this, [ doTimeout + args[0] ].concat( args ) );

    return typeof args[0] === 'number' || typeof args[1] === 'number'
      ? this
      : result;
  };

  function p_doTimeout( jquery_data_key ) {
    var that = this,
      elem,
      data = {},

      // Allows the plugin to call a string callback method.
      method_base = jquery_data_key ? $.fn : $,

      // Any additional arguments will be passed to the callback.
      args = arguments,
      slice_args = 4,

      id        = args[1],
      delay     = args[2],
      callback  = args[3];

    if ( typeof id !== 'string' ) {
      slice_args--;

      id        = jquery_data_key = 0;
      delay     = args[1];
      callback  = args[2];
    }

    // If id is passed, store a data reference either as .data on the first
    // element in a jQuery collection, or in the internal cache.
    if ( jquery_data_key ) { // Note: key is 'doTimeout' + id

      // Get id-object from the first element's data, otherwise initialize it to {}.
      elem = that.eq(0);
      elem.data( jquery_data_key, data = elem.data( jquery_data_key ) || {} );

    } else if ( id ) {
      // Get id-object from the cache, otherwise initialize it to {}.
      data = cache[ id ] || ( cache[ id ] = {} );
    }

    // Clear any existing timeout for this id.
    data.id && clearTimeout( data.id );
    delete data.id;

    // Clean up when necessary.
    function cleanup() {
      if ( jquery_data_key ) {
        elem.removeData( jquery_data_key );
      } else if ( id ) {
        delete cache[ id ];
      }
    };

    // Yes, there actually is a setTimeout call in here!
    function actually_setTimeout() {
      data.id = setTimeout( function(){ data.fn(); }, delay );
    };

    if ( callback ) {
      // A callback (and delay) were specified. Store the callback reference for
      // possible later use, and then setTimeout.
      data.fn = function( no_polling_loop ) {

        // If the callback value is a string, it is assumed to be the name of a
        // method on $ or $.fn depending on where doTimeout was executed.
        if ( typeof callback === 'string' ) {
          callback = method_base[ callback ];
        }

        callback.apply( that, aps.call( args, slice_args ) ) === true && !no_polling_loop

          // Since the callback returned true, and we're not specifically
          // canceling a polling loop, do it again!
          ? actually_setTimeout()

          // Otherwise, clean up and quit.
          : cleanup();
      };

      // Set that timeout!
      actually_setTimeout();

    } else if ( data.fn ) {
      // No callback passed. If force_mode (delay) is true, execute the data.fn
      // callback immediately, continuing any callback return-true polling loop.
      // If force_mode is false, execute the data.fn callback immediately but do
      // NOT continue a callback return-true polling loop. If force_mode is
      // undefined, simply clean up. Since data.fn was still defined, whatever
      // was supposed to happen hadn't yet, so return true.
      delay === undefined ? cleanup() : data.fn( delay === false );
      return true;

    } else {
      // Since no callback was passed, and data.fn isn't defined, it looks like
      // whatever was supposed to happen already did. Clean up and quit!
      cleanup();
    }

  };

})(jQuery);




//CSS3 Animate-it
$('.animatedParent').appear();
$('.animatedClick').click(function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('data-target');


  if($(this).attr('data-sequence') != undefined){
    var firstId = $("."+target+":first").attr('data-id');
    var lastId = $("."+target+":last").attr('data-id');
    var number = firstId;

    //Add or remove the class
    if($("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").hasClass('go')){
      $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('goAway');
      $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").removeClass('go');
    }else{
      $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('go');
      $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").removeClass('goAway');
    }
    number ++;
    delay = Number($(this).attr('data-sequence'));
    $.doTimeout(delay, function(){
      console.log(lastId);

      //Add or remove the class
      if($("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").hasClass('go')){
        $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('goAway');
        $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").removeClass('go');
      }else{
        $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('go');
        $("."+target+"[data-id="+ number +"]").removeClass('goAway');
      }

      //increment
      ++number;

      //continute looping till reached last ID
      if(number <= lastId){return true;}
    });
  }else{
    if($('.'+target).hasClass('go')){
      $('.'+target).addClass('goAway');
      $('.'+target).removeClass('go');
    }else{
      $('.'+target).addClass('go');
      $('.'+target).removeClass('goAway');
    }
  } 
});

$(document.body).on('appear', '.animatedParent', function(e, $affected){
  var ele = $(this).find('.animated');
  var parent = $(this);


  if(parent.attr('data-sequence') != undefined){

    var firstId = $(this).find('.animated:first').attr('data-id');
    var number = firstId;
    var lastId = $(this).find('.animated:last').attr('data-id');

    $(parent).find(".animated[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('go');
    number ++;
    delay = Number(parent.attr('data-sequence'));

    $.doTimeout(delay, function(){
      $(parent).find(".animated[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('go');
      ++number;
      if(number <= lastId){return true;}
    });
  }else{
    ele.addClass('go');
  }

});

 $(document.body).on('disappear', '.animatedParent', function(e, $affected) {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('animateOnce')){
    $(this).find('.animated').removeClass('go');
   }
 });

 $(window).load(function(){
  $.force_appear();
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using "appear" jQuery plugin? If you do this is how it should look like something like this:

```
$('.animatedParent').appear(function(e, $affected){
           var ele = $(this).find('.animated');
           var parent = $(this);


         if(parent.attr('data-sequence') != undefined){

        var firstId = $(this).find('.animated:first').attr('data-id');
        var number = firstId;
        var lastId = $(this).find('.animated:last').attr('data-id');

        $(parent).find(".animated[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('go');
        number ++;
        delay = Number(parent.attr('data-sequence'));

        $.doTimeout(delay, function(){
          $(parent).find(".animated[data-id="+ number +"]").addClass('go');
          ++number;
          if(number <= lastId){return true;}
        });
      }else{
        ele.addClass('go');
      }  
    });
```